# Is it possible to suppress top-level this errors?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using 6to5 to compile ES6 code snippets but get `ReferenceError: unknown: Line 1: Top level this is undefined in strict mode` errors when compiling e.g.

```
var to5 = require('6to5');
to5.transform('this.x = 42').code
```

The error makes sense but I want to compile snippets that reference `this`, is there any way to suppress the error and continue compiling?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to compile invalid snippets?

Comment: I'm playing around with the Riotjs tag compiler, it compiles JS snippets which it injects into compiled JS, See: https://muut.com/riotjs/compiler.html

Comment: Here's the source of the problem: https://muut.com/riotjs/forum/#!/using:problem-referencing-this-in -- problem is my proposed solution won't work.